# How to make documentation with NetBeans and Javadoc

Tags: netbeans, project, javadoc

I was searching a while, but nothing found. How can i make documentation in NetBeans 7.0.1?

My file looks like:

```
/** Class Description of MyClass */
public class ScanReader{
}
```

In my project properties i checked all options with checkbox and nothing in Javadoc options (i tried -d with global path, but nothing happened).
When i make build or build and clean i dont see anything about documentation and nothing new in project file either.

Comment: u want to generate javadoc HTML files?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Right click your project in Project window and click **'Generate Javadoc'**

[image: Netbeans generate javadoc]

Comment: Thanks, but how can i do it only for 1 file?

Comment: That is not possible, I think. But once it generates for all the classes, goto your project folder/dist/javadoc/package-name and open the HTML of your required class

Comment: How can I view the document after it has been created?

Comment: @JohnHogan Open the generated HTML file in your browser

Answer (score 17):

**Update**: for those using NetBeans 8.0, besides the options already stated, you can create Javadoc for a file or package.

- Right click over file/package
- Tools > Analyze Javadoc
- "Analyzer" window should appear, noting which Javadoc is missing, with the corresponding "Create missing Javadoc for [method]"
- Check the ones you want, click on "Fix Selected".

Done :)

Answer (score 7):

This is another way that you can generate your Javadoc through Netbeans.

1.- Click on 'Run' menu

2.- Then go down to 'Generate Javadoc (...)'

[image]

Comment: Where is the resulting HTML document stored?

Comment: @kurdtpage It's in the project's "dist" folder.